# Proper way to clean up a Python service -- atexit, signal, try/finally

Tags: python, daemon

I have a single threaded Python 2.7 daemon/service running on Debian. I have some critical cleanup code that disables certain hardware features.

```
import sys
import atexit
import signal
from my_job import give_high_fives
from my_cleanup import prevent_the_apocalypse

atexit.register(prevent_the_apocalypse)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, prevent_the_apocalypse)
signal.signal(signal.SIGHUP, prevent_the_apocalypse)
try:
    while True:
        give_high_fives()
finally:
    prevent_the_apocalypse()
```

This looks paranoid, and I also don't like calling the cleanup code so many times. Right now it looks like cleanup is called 3 or 4 times on a `SIGTERM`.

Is there one single way to `prevent_the_apocalypse` exactly once in all possible exit conditions?

Comment: there should be one, and only one, obvious way, eh?

Comment: If you're writing a daemon without using the [`daemon`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/) library, I'm willing to bet you get a whole lot of things wrong. See [PEP 3143](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3143/) for all of the issues you have to deal with.

Answer (score 6):

Writing a correct daemon in Python is hard. In fact, it's hard in *any* language. [PEP 3143](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3143) explains the issues.

The [`daemon`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/) module wraps up most of the details so you don't have to get them right. If you use that, it becomes very easy to add cleanup code.

One option is to just subclass `daemon.DaemonContext` and put it there. For example:

```
class MyDaemonContext(daemon.DaemonContext):
    def close(self):
        if not self.is_open:
            return
        prevent_the_apocalypse()
        super(MyDaemonContext, self).close()

with MyDaemonContext():
    while True:
        give_high_fives()
```

The `daemon` module already sets up the signal handlers so that they do what you've configured them to do, but without skipping the `close` method. (The `close` will be run exactly once—in the context's `__exit__`, in an `atexit` method, or possibly elsewhere, as appropriate.)

If you want something more complicated, where some signals skip `close` and others don't, instead of subclassing, just set its `signal_map` appropriately.

Comment: I'd change "Writing a correct daemon in Python is hard. " to "Writing a correct daemon, in any language, is hard." Python has nothing to do with all the issues involved with "tearing down" a daemon process.

Comment: I fall in exactly the same issue and solved it with the same module, upvoted !

Comment: @Bakuriu: Good point. It's only really harder in Python than in C because (a) all the documentation out there is for C, and (b) nobody coding in C expects to be able to use try/finally, with, etc. to guarantee execution of their code. So, edited, and thanks.

Comment: @Gcmalloc: Me too. :) Too bad Ben Finney doesn't have time to maintain it in the stdlib; otherwise it would have come with 3.3 or 3.4, and a lot more people would be using it…

Answer (score -1):

Have your signal handlers do nothing but set a global variable to true.  Then check that variable in your main loop and break out if it is true, running your cleanup handler as you exit.

Comment: This doesn't seem a clean solution. Also, the OP goal is not only to avoid multiple calls to the clean-up function, but to avoid specifying it more than once. Your answer doesn't address the main problem in the question.

Comment: If you want to catch all those signals, you are going to need call signal.signal for each of them.  You can pass the same handler to each though.  Also, the OP indicated that the main problem was calling the cleanup handler more than once, so indeed my answer does address that.